# Working out the time complexity

Tags: python, big-o

I have have the following code:

```
for i in alist:
    if i not in alist:
        result.append(i)
```

I am not sure whether that would be `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`, because of the `in` statement?

Comment: You're going to get an empty `result` list.

Comment: Time complexity is difficult to estimate in Python. You need to know the type of `alist` and how it implements [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

Answer (score 1):

That would be O(n^2) because you have two loops(one of them is nested inside another one) which iterate through all elements in the list. One loop caused by "in" another one caused by "not in".

You can read more about implementation details of "in" and "not in" [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Also "in" and "not in" operators may have different implementation for different data types as well as different algorithm complexity.

Comment: As a side note. [This page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on Pythons wiki is great for complexity related stuff.